# split button does not toggle Angular, JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have seen some questions similar to this one but I haven't come across an answer that would help. Can anyone please have a look at my code?

I have {{$ctrl.init}} and {{$ctrl.people}} assigned in the component. I know this assignment works because if I take away the "split-button" and just print them on the template directly, I can click on them and they redirect normally, with no problem.

This is the code in my template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <!--Sidebar content-->
       <div class="btn-group btn-xs" uib-dropdown ng-cloak>
         <button id="mydd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">Action
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="mydd">
              <li><a href="{{$ctrl.init}}">Start</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{$ctrl.people}}">People</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I add the button, I get the proper styling but it doesn't drop down or show me the options. There is no reaction.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

you should add `ui.bootstrap` module to main app .

in controller define  `$scope.isCollapsed = true;` 
and also add `uib-collapse="isCollapsed"` directive to `ul` tag

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
   <!--Sidebar content-->
   <div class="btn-group btn-xs" uib-dropdown ng-cloak>
     <button id="mydd" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle     btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">Action
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-collapse="isCollapsed" role="menu" aria-labelledby="mydd">
          <li><a href="{{$ctrl.init}}">Start</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{$ctrl.people}}">People</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```